# React select 508 compliance

Tags: select, accessibility, reactjs, voiceover, standards-compliance

I'm trying to make a react select component 508 compliant and usable from OSX voiceover by implementing some aria roles. The component is here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

The issue I am running into is being able to navigate/choose items from the list, and also being able to remove items that have been selected(when multi select mode is used). So far I have been able to allow opening the selections, and choosing them just by adding aria button roles to the options. Any ideas on how to make a select 508 compliant? I have tried using aria listbox, menu, navigation, tree to no avail!

Comment: You should aim a bit higher than 508 because 508 is about to be changed to WCAG 2 AA and 508 does not actually specify what should happen with dynamic applications. So if you want accessibility, choose WCAG 2 AA

Comment: I see, yeah that's definitely what I'm aiming for. I want the component to be very usable from the keyboard and voiceover. I actually have it working pretty decently now from Voice over.

Comment: I know that listbox and combobox roles are not possible to (at least, I could not) get to work in a cross-patform and cross-AT way (as of November 2014) without at least one issue on each major combination. Menu roles might be your best bet.

Comment: I ended up using a similar solution to the way google maps combo box works. With javascript to navigate the options with normal up and down keys, and the options go up to the select box when they are navigated to, so the screen reader reads them.